# Как подключиться к серверу в контейнере Docker из браузера?

Tags: python, django, docker, ip

Создал контейнер Docker, запустил такой командой:

```
docker run -it -p 8000:8000 -v "/path/to/smth":/path/to/smth/else -w /path/to/smth/else container_name
```

Внутри докера запустил сервер Django:

```
python3.6 manage.py runserver
```

Django пишет, что сервер доступен по адресу 127.0.0.1:8000. Забиваю адрес в Chrome, не подключается. Также пробовал вместо 127.0.0.1 подставлять адрес, возвращаемый `hostname -i` – безрезультатно.

Вопрос: в чём проблема и как всё-таки подключиться к серверу?

Comment: Запускать через runserver 0.0.0.0:8000

Comment: @andreymal, да, спасибо. Вынесите в ответ, если хотите